# How to embed HTML created by Dreamweaver into an ASP.NET applicaton

Tags: asp.net, html, dreamweaver

I've been asked by a friend, who created a very visually appealing website mostly in Dreamweaver, to add some database backed functionality that I really only know how to do in ASP.NET. The problem is when I load his generated HTML into an ASPX page it renders it quite horribly. I've tried adding a basic .html page to an ASP.NET project but it still looks funky. He's on a Mac and i'm (obviously) using a Windows box. Is there a clean way to take a quite complete (but quite static) website and add ASP.NET functionality to it?  Any comments are very much welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit your own question...but I do have all the stylesheets and images correctly mapped. Everything *works* is just doesn't look near as good as it did in the Safari browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought.

You state in your comment:

> Everything *works* is just doesn't look near as good as it did in the Safari browser

Where doesn't it look as good as it did in the Safari browser? When served as a page from a webserver (either the built-in cassini server, or IIS) in IE/Firefox, or when you switch to design view in Visual Studio?

Visual Studio has a lot of trouble rendering things correctly - it's really not standards compliant by anyone's definition - VS2010 is apparently much better - for example, try looking at this page: [display/box/float/clear test](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS1/current/test5526c.htm) in a browser and in the VS designer - very different.

If you mean in the browser, which browser? Have you tried looking at it Firefox instead? It's possible that if it's been built to look nice in Safari that it will work in Firefox, but there may be issues with the rendering/layouts in IE - this is a fairly well known issue.

If all the stylesheets are being correctly called (check with [Firebug](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS1/current/test5526c.htm) for Firefox for example) then there are probably some issues with the CSS that need to be addressed for IE.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET does not alter the rendering of standard HTML. So there must be some other issue like a missing stylesheet (either all together or a broken link) or images. Once you have the HTML properly copied over and solve the display issue, you can add in the ASP.NET controls and code you need to make it functional.